# shipping cheese

Tags: food-safety, food-preservation

I bought cheese blocks at the store, unwrapped them, divided them into smaller pieces, cold smoked them, and repackaged them with a seal a meal vacuum
system.  Will they be safe to eat if I ship them ground from Oregon to Michigan?

Comment: What cheese? There's thousands of varieties.

Answer (score 3):

Lot's of food companies ship all sorts of foods, all of the time.  While simply boxing up your cheese and sending it on the slow route from OR to MI would invite spoilage, you could package it an insulated container, include ice packs, and speed up the delivery.  This will cost you, but your cheese will be better off.

Answer (score 1):

Spoilage is directly related to water. Cheese has a high concentration of water, therefore yes, there is a high probability it will spoil in transit... smoked or not.

Food savers go a long way to protect food from bacteria *entering* the sealed package, but nothing to prevent the growth of what is already on the cheese when packaged.

Comment: "*...nothing to prevent the growth of what is already on the cheese when packaged*" Except perhaps salts and acids, which some chesses can have plenty of. The smoking process may have reduced the moisture content and some cheeses have lower moisture to start with.